# pass object type to std::array constructor

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to rewrite `java` code using `c++`. I am not proficient in c++ at all.

Original `java` code

```
public static <T, K> K[] toArray(ITemplateCommand<T, K> command, List<T> templates) {
    if (null == templates) {
        return null;
    }
    K[] array = (K[]) Array.newInstance(command.getClassOfK(), templates.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < templates.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = command.buildTemplate(templates.get(i));
    }
    return array;
}
```

My `c++` code.

```
class TemplateImplementation {

    public:
        template<class K, class T>
        static K* toArray(ITemplateCommand<T,K> *command, std::list<T>& templates) {
            if (nullptr == templates) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            std::array<command->getClassOfK(), templates.size()> arr; // no idea how to pass object type there
            for(int i = 0; i < templates.size(); i++) {
                arr[i] = command->buildTemplate(templates[i]);
            }
        }
};
```

In `java` I created interface and multiple implementation where `getClassOfK` returned class of `K` object.

Here to simplify things I decided to not creat implementations but only class with `virtual` methods which serves as inteface.

```
template<class T, class K>
class ITemplateCommand {
public:
    virtual K* buildTemplate(T* tmplate);

    virtual std::type_info getClassOfK();
};
```

But I have several errors during compilation(I am using online `c++` compiler)

```
sh-4.2# g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                          
main.cpp: In static member function 'static K* TemplateImplementation::toArray(ITemplateCommand<T, K>*, std::list<T>&)':                                                                                                                      
main.cpp:24:64: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> struct std::array'                                                                                        
             std::array<command->getClassOfK(), templates.size()> arr; // no idea how to pass object type there                                                                                                                               
                                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                             
main.cpp:24:64: error:   expected a type, got 'command->.getClassOfK()'                                                                                                                                                                       
main.cpp:24:69: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token                                                                                                                                                                           
             std::array<command->getClassOfK(), templates.size()> arr; // no idea how to pass object type there                                                                                                                               
                                                                     ^                                                                                                                                                                        
main.cpp:26:22: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript                                                                                                                                                                           
                 arr[i] = command->buildTemplate(templates[i]);
```

But my main question is **how to pass class type to constructor of std::array using std::type_info? Or it's not possible using this object?**

P.S. Also I know it's not a good idea to return pointers from function but I want to keep code as close as possible to original

Comment: There's a fundamental mismatch going on here. C++ templates are based on compile time specialization so you cannot create a template from a run-time value.

Comment: Hm...So it's not possible to rewrite original code?

Comment: It is, you just need to understand c++. Start by looking at std::vector, and how c++ template parameters are used.

Comment: Oh! I get the problem! I don't need `getClassOfK` at all. Because of using `template` declaration I simply can do `std::array<K, templates.size()> arr;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things wrong with this line:

```
std::array<command->getClassOfK(), templates.size()> arr;
```

The [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class template needs to be instantiated with two things: a type, and a constant-expression that is convertible to a `size_t`. Both of those things need to be available *at compile time*. `templates.size()` is based on the number of elements in that `list` at *runtime*, so converting a `list<T>` to a `std::array<K, N>` is impossible. The second problem is that `getClassOfK()` is not a type - it's a function that returns an object - that's just not at all what `array` needs. That's the simpler problem though, you need to pass in the type of `K` and you already have it: it's just `K`. The last problem is that you want to return a `K*` and a `array<K,N>` is **not** a `K*`.

The right way to write this code is to use a *dynamic* container. Specifically, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
template<class K, class T>
static std::vector<K*> toArray(ITemplateCommand<T,K> *command, std::list<T>& templates) {
    std::vector<K*> vec;
    vec.reserve(templates.size());
    for (T& tmpl : templates) {
        vec.push_back(command->buildTemplate(tmpl));
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Hm. So solution with `std::array<K, templates.size()> arr;` won't work?

Comment: @user1432980 No. `templates.size()` isn't a constant expression, it can only be evaluated at runtime. You *could* simply return a simple array (`K* arr = new K[templates.size()];`), but using `vector` is strongly preferred.

Comment: Oh! So if I had fixed `size` It could have worked? I mean passing `K` there.